# How to change the language based on user preference in Yii2?

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

my site start with a default language(which is English) then based on user's preference i should change it. is this possible in Yii2 ? is there any widget for this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use contentNegotiator, without assign a language to the user the language is automatically assigned by the application.

for this 
In config/main.php in bootstrap section start the component

```
'bootstrap' => [
    'log',
    'contentNegotiator',
],
```

in component section

```
'components' => [
    'contentNegotiator' =>[
        'class' => 'yii\filters\ContentNegotiator',
        'languages' => [
                'en-US',
                'it-IT',
                'fr-FR',
        ],
    ],

],
```

otherwise you can change when and where  you want. Is application action eg you can do in any controller you chose. this way

```
 \Yii::$app->language = 'zh-CN';
```

Comment: how can a user select a language in here?

Comment: Is automatically assigned  by the system language of user

Comment: so if users system language is english and he wants to use french there is no way ha?

Comment: I have update my answer. (the content negotiator is a suggestion but you can chanfe where you want).